# finite sum of fractions

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

Consider a weighted average where each summand is drawn from a uniform districution.

Suppose $x_i$ is drawn from the uniform distribution $[0,1]$. For the sake of tractability, let's assume $x_i<1$.

Let the weighted sum be $\bar x = \frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i$.

Is there an analytic form I can derive similar to what we dervie for (i) the sum of the first $n$ terms of a geometric series and (ii) as $n\rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: Do you know about the strong law of large numbers? What is your level in probability theory?

Comment: @MushuNrek I do know the strong law of large numbers! intermediate - probability theory. Can you help me understand this problem?

Comment: If you are familiar with the strong law of large numbers, then this should answer (ii) as it gives an a.s. limit of this type of sums. For (i), you might want to have a look at [this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin%E2%80%93Hall_distribution).

Comment: @MushuNrek Excellent. I googled that too and read about the distribution. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's define: $$\;{ \large \bar{x}_n} = \dfrac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i \;$$

Then for each $n$, ${ \large \bar{x}_n}$ is a random variable over $[0,1]$ with a probability distribution, called the [Bates distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bates_distribution).